# how to join 100 or more tables without condition in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

how to join 100 or more tables without condition  in Codeigniter

$query=$this->input->get('term');

```
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from("user");
        $this->db->join("sell", 'user.id = sell.id');
        $this->db->like('name', $query);
        $this->db->or_like('address', $query);
        $this->db->or_like('email', $query);
        $this->db->or_like('contact', $query);
        $this->db->or_like('gender', $query);
        $this->db->or_like('id', $query);
        // $this->db->or_like('product_name', $query);
        // $this->db->or_like('product_description', $query);
        // $this->db->or_like('product_price', $query);
        $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
        $data =$this->db->get()->result();
```

Comment: Hey bud, why do you have so many tables to join?  Joins require a condition to _join_ the data on... I think you maybe asking about a UNION, but I am not sure.  Can you please add more details to your question, specifically about the data you are trying to connect and how you want to connect it.

Comment: response search box to ajax request  to all table data

Comment: please answer how to all table data i will select

Comment: set one common field to all table and using join query join all the table

Comment: for eg (select * from table left outer join table1 on table1.id =  table.id left outer join table2 on table2.id = table.id.........goes on)

Comment: for eg; $this->db->select('*');$this->db->join('table1', 'table1.id = table.id,'left outer');$this->db->join('table2', 'table2.id = table.id,'left outer');$result = $this->db->get(table')->result_array();

Comment: If you want a good answer, It would help to clarify your question.